# scrlayer-scrpage: Changing text font in header

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, scrlayer-scrpage, scrreprt

I'm using `scrreprt` for my class notes and changed the page layout to my likings. However firstly I would like to change the font of my page header to `\mdseries` to match the chapter prefix.

I'm also using the option `headsepline`, but want to remove the line between "Chapter prefix" and "Chapter name".

Any help would be appreciated.

**M W E:**

```
\documentclass[
    numbers=endperiod,
    toc=chapterentrydotfill,
    DIV=12
    ]
    {scrreprt}
    
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[
  automark,
  autooneside=false,
  headsepline=true
    ]
    {scrlayer-scrpage}
    \pagestyle{scrheadings}
    \cohead{\Ifthispageodd{\rightmark}{\leftmark}}
    \cfoot*{\pagemark}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\let\raggedchapter\centering

\setkomafont{chapterprefix}{\normalsize\mdseries}
\KOMAoption{chapterprefix}{true}

\renewcommand{\chapterheadmidvskip}{%
    \par\nobreak\vskip -.1cm {\rule{\textwidth}{.5pt}}\par%
}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=0pt,afterskip=15pt]{chapter}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\tracingpatches
\xpatchcmd{\@@makeschapterhead}{%for the unnumbered
    \usekomafont{chapter}{#1}\par
}{%
    \usekomafont{chapter}{\MakeUppercase{#1}}\par
}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\@@makechapterhead}{%for numbered
    \usekomafont{chapter}{#1}\par
}{%
    \usekomafont{chapter}{\MakeUppercase{#1}}\par
}{}{}
\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
    \mbox{\huge\MakeUppercase{\chapappifchapterprefix{\nobreakspace}}\thechapter\autodot
    \IfUsePrefixLine{}{\enskip}}%
}

\renewcommand{\abstract}[1]{%
    \textbf{Abstract.} #1\par%
}

\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \setcounter{page}{0}
    
    \chapter{The Chapter Numbered One}
        \abstract{\lipsum[3]}
        
        \section{The Section Which Comes First}
            \lipsum
            
            \subsection{First Subsection}
                \lipsum
        
\end{document}
```

Comment: for the page header you can use `\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\mdseries} `. But beside this: I would avoid to patch internal commands like this. This is not reliable and actually your patches don't do nothing for me (with a current KOMA) as `\@@makeschapterhead` has changed there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there should be no line between chapter prefix and chapter name, remove the redefinition of `\chapterheadmidvskip`. (Off topic: `\chapterheadmidvskip` should not be used to insert such a line.) The vertical space between chapter prefix and chapter name can be adjusted by option `innerskip`, eg.:

```latex
\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=0pt,afterskip=15pt,innerskip=7.5pt]{chapter}
```

If chapter prefix and chapter name should be uppercase, redefine `\chapterlineswithprefixformat`:

```latex
\renewcommand*{\chapterlineswithprefixformat}[3]{%
  \Ifstr{#1}{chapter}
    {\MakeUppercase{#2#3}}
    {#2#3}%
}
```

If chapter prefix should be `\huge` use

```latex
\setkomafont{chapterprefix}{\mdseries\huge}
```

If the page header should be upshape use either `\addtokomafont{pagehead}{\upshape}` or `\addtokomafont{pageheadfoot}{\upshape}`.

```latex
\documentclass[
  numbers=endperiod,
  toc=chapterentrydotfill,
  DIV=12
]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{lipsum}% only for dummy text

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% only needed with outdated TeX distributions
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\usepackage[
  automark,
  autooneside=false,
  headsepline=true
]{scrlayer-scrpage}% sets page style scrheadinges automatically
\clearpairofpagestyles
\chead{\ifodd\value{page}\rightmark\else\leftmark\fi}
\cfoot*{\pagemark}
\addtokomafont{pageheadfoot}{\upshape}

\let\raggedchapter\centering
\setkomafont{chapterprefix}{\mdseries\huge}
\KOMAoption{chapterprefix}{true}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=0pt,afterskip=15pt,innerskip=7.5pt]{chapter}
\renewcommand*{\chapterlineswithprefixformat}[3]{%
  \Ifstr{#1}{chapter}
    {\MakeUppercase{#2#3}}
    {#2#3}%
}

\renewcommand{\abstract}[1]{%
    \textbf{Abstract.} #1\par%
}

\BeforeStartingTOC[toc]{\thispagestyle{empty}\pagestyle{empty}}
\AfterStartingTOC[toc]{\clearpage}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\tableofcontents

\cleardoubleoddpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\chapter{The Chapter Numbered One}
\abstract{\lipsum[3]}

\section{The Section Which Comes First}
\lipsum
\subsection{First Subsection}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]